# Google spreadsheet API v4 with PHP - how to insert empty row to beginning

Tags: php, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

I am confused about the new Google Sheets API v4.
My question is: how can I insert a row to the beginning of the spreadsheet?

I can't find any useful tutorial for the new Google Sheet API v4 or find viable documentation from Google specific to PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this,

```
$requests = new Google_Service_Sheets_Request(array(
    'insertDimension' => array(
        'range' => array(
            'sheetId' => 0,
            'dimension' => "ROWS",
            'startIndex' => 1,
            'endIndex' => 2
        )
    )
));


$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(array(
    'requests' => $requests
));


$this->service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($this->sheetID, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

where $this->service is instance of Google_Service_Sheets and $this->sheetID is your SheetID from google docs url

Comment: I got error with this. I got it working by not using the class `Google_Service_Sheets_Request` and directly adding the requests body to the `requests` parameter of the `Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest`

Comment: How I can get my sheetId by the sheet name?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it:

```
//Insert blank new row between R1 and R2 (there is no R0)
$dr = new Google_Service_Sheets_DimensionRange();
$dr->setSheetId(0);//first sheet/tab of spreadsheet file
$dr->setDimension('ROWS');
$dr->setStartIndex(1);
$dr->setEndIndex(2);
$ins = new Google_Service_Sheets_InsertDimensionRequest();
$ins->setRange($dr);
$ins->setInheritFromBefore(false);
$ssr = new Google_Service_Sheets_Request();
$ssr->setInsertDimension($ins);
$busr = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
$busr->setRequests([$ssr]);
$response = $sheetsService->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $busr, []);
```